# .addclass() function not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a html div as below.

```
<div class="product-layout">
      <div class="product-thumb">
        <div class="image"> 
          <h1>welcome</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

when i use addclass function to the class product layout it is not working.

```
 $(".product-layout").addClass("dontshow");
```

This is the way i have specified. Please let me know if there is a solution.

Comment: do you want in onload

Comment: Show your related code it's hard to guess

Answer (score 2):

if you want addClass in onload please try this. you should include jquery plugin

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".product-layout").addClass("dontshow");
});
```

```css
.dontshow{
  background-color:#f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-layout">
      <div class="product-thumb">
        <div class="image"> 
          <h1>welcome</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated class with jquery and please make sure put your script at bottom of your page , mean footer bottom.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".product-layout").addClass("dontshow");
});
```

```css
.dontshow {
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-layout">
        <div class="product-thumb">
          <div class="image"> 
            <h1>welcome</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```